# Where to place headings/dimension names in table/matrix?

Tags: gui-design, tables, column-headers

Let's say I want to show how many people graduated from my university. I know their fields of study and their degrees. I want to offer different views on this data, for example a chart, a flat table, and something similar to this:

[image: Table]

This table is like a matrix view with sums. I'm just wondering where to put the headings or names of the two dimensions.

I've seen a lot of tables which use the solution that I marked red in the image which means putting both in the otherwise empty table cell in the top left corner. But I think it doesn't look good and it ruins the "cleanness" with the unaligend words and the slanted line.

Also often you see the blue solution, putting the headings as a container around (above/beside) the columns/rows. The row-heading is sometimes rotated by 90 degrees. I still don't think this is the perfect solution.

Is there a well accepted or standard way to do this? Which option is preferable?

Note: In my actual case, I don't know how many rows and columns I get, but it's something between 3 and 10 each, so still readable in this format. Moreover, it is important to show the two headings, as it is not clear from the data itself what is meant.

Answer (score 1):

The Title ( and maybe subtitle ) should convey this information.

I took the liberty of freeing your data from it's cells, pivoting the table,adding some breathing room and other niceties, this is not part of your question, but I think the whole table should strive for muted unbiased clarity.

[image]

Comment: Convey which information? Sure, the table was just a sketch, it's not going to look exactly like that. So, in essence, your suggestion would be to add the information in the "total" column/row... I didn't think of that but I have to say that I find it a bit confusing to look for this information at the ends (right, bottom) of the table. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Oh, the title of my table, sorry I thought you meant the title of my question ;-)